# Can you get the Rep Cap hat from hitting the cap before 12:00 UTC on the first day of Winter Bash 2021?

Tags: support, bug, winter-bash, daily-reputation-limit, winter-bash-2021

I've have hit the reputation cap on RPG today, and have not gotten the Rep Cap hat yet. However, I had already reached the cap before Winter Bash opened at 12:00 UTC. Additionally, I have had enough upvotes after it opened to have hit rep cap again.

I'll most likely hit it again tomorrow, so it isn't a a huge deal to me, but I did ask Yaakov in chat if it was earnable today, and he said:

> [should be](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59891445#59891445)

Comment: I have the same question regarding both the Rep Cap and also the Hi5 hat. I thought I had earned them Dec. 15 on music.stackexchange.com, but have not seen them yet. Being a relatively low volume site, it's possible I can "re-earn" the Rep Cap, but near impossible for Hi5. Bug? Delay? Some criteria I missed? ...?